# NHibernate (Fluent mapping) ReferencesAny<object>

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Base entity interface is IEntity which requires only "object ID {get;set;}" to be implemented.
Now, in almost every case ID is of Guid type (except for membership etc).
I am using following code to do mapping of interface

```
...
    AnyPart<IEntity> primaryMap = ReferencesAny(x => x.Primary)
                    .IdentityType<object>() // tried with .IdentityType<Guid>()
                    .EntityIdentifierColumn("PrimaryID")
                    .EntityTypeColumn("PrimaryType")
                    .MetaType<string>();
...
```

Of course, next I am adding meta values.

So, Now getting error

**Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bound**

And with **`.IdentityType<Guid>()`**

**could not resolve property: Primary.ID of: Founder.Connection [.SingleOrDefault[Founder.Connection](NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Founder.Connection], Quote((x, ) => (OrElse(AndAlso(Equal(x.Primary.ID, 35c2142a-4c17-4b77-96fd-a2570028a211), Equal(x.Secondary.ID, 35c2142a-4c17-4b77-96fd-a2570028a211)), AndAlso(Equal(x.Secondary.ID, 35c2142a-4c17-4b77-96fd-a2570028a211), Equal(x.Primary.ID, 35c2142a-4c17-4b77-96fd-a2570028a211))))), )]**

**UPDATE**:

I tried also with `.IdentityType(x=>x.ID)` but same problem (Source array was not long enough)

**UPDATE II**:

Query (Actually whole method containing query) that this error occurs on is bellow:

```
public IQueryable<Connection> GetConnections(IEntity connectable)
        {
            IQueryable<Connection> query =
                Query().Where(
                    x => x.Primary.ID == connectable.ID || x.Secondary.ID == connectable.ID);
            return query;
        }
```

Comment: The second error looks like produced by a query. Which query?

Comment: I updated (Update II) my answer with query. Aso note that even Guid is used in 90% case I have to stick with object type.

Comment: Try this in the query: `x.Primary == connectable` (without ID).

Comment: Thanks, this did help. However I would like to find out what is behind and why the one with object didn't work. Stefan, If you could just post this as answer so I can set it is accepted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the query: `x.Primary == connectable` (without `ID`).

The problem is that you reference an `object` (or another unmapped type, that's why you need an `any` mapping). There is no `ID` on `object`.

By the way, using HQL would allow you to access the id by using the keyword `id`, which is not available in Linq (technically it could be made available as extension method, but I don't know Linq to NH good enough to say if it had been implemented). Every `any` reference conceptually has an `id` and a `class`.